# Lodash is undefined when testing a Svelte app with Jest

Tags: jestjs, lodash, es6-modules, svelte

I'm trying to use Jest to test my Svelte project, and everything I've read says that I need to include svelte-jester to transform my Svelte code into something that Jest can process (CommonJS, I think?). This seems to work fine, except that I'm importing Lodash into some of my Svelte components but Jest, when running its tests, is reporting that Lodash is undefined. (In a browser environment, everything seems to be working as expected.)

To demonstrate the issue, I copied and slightly modified an example from the testing-library website:

```
// Comp.svelte

<script>
  import _ from 'lodash';

  export let name
</script>

<h1>Hello {_.toUpper(name)}!</h1>
```

and then my test file is

```js
// tests/Comp.test.js

import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'

import { render } from '@testing-library/svelte'

import Comp from '../Comp'

test('shows proper heading when rendered', () => {
  const { getByText } = render(Comp, { name: 'World' })

  expect(getByText('Hello WORLD!')).toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

The relevant part of my package.json is the following, which I also got from the testing-library website.

```json
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.16",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^16.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^10.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/svelte": "^3.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "rollup": "^2.3.4",
    "rollup-plugin-svelte": "^7.0.0",
    "svelte": "^3.0.0",
    "svelte-jester": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
  },
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.svelte$": ["svelte-jester", { "debug": true }]
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "svelte"
    ],
  }
}
```

The test output indicates that, in the compiled version of `Comp.svelte`, Lodash is undefined:

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpper' of undefined

      5 | </script>
      6 |
    > 7 | <h1>Hello {_.toUpper(name)}!</h1>
        |              ^

      at create_fragment (src/Comp.svelte:7:14)
      at init (node_modules/svelte/internal/index.js:1489:37)
      at new Comp (src/Comp.svelte:83:3)
      at render (node_modules/@testing-library/svelte/dist/pure.js:81:21)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/tests/Comp.spec.js:9:25)
```

The compiled version of the component seems to indicate that, at a minimum, Lodash is being `require`-d into the build.

```
/* Comp.svelte generated by Svelte v3.31.0 */
"use strict";

const { SvelteComponentDev, add_location, append_dev, detach_dev, dispatch_dev, element, flush, init, insert_dev, noop, safe_not_equal, set_data_dev, text, validate_slots } = require("svelte/internal");
const { default: _ } = require("lodash");
const file = "Comp.svelte";

// etc.
```

Can someone please tell me what I need to do to get Lodash to be properly exported and/or required into the build for a Jest test? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

you can check this [issue](https://github.com/mihar-22/svelte-jester/issues/4),

it's undefined because it is a CommonJS module module.exports = x and you are importing it as an ES module. If you do import * as get from 'lodash/get' it'll work.